# key-value database with set datatype

Tags: database, redis, key-value

Redis has such type. So one is able to check wherever a value exists in set. Add to set , delete from set etc.

But data is big and Redis stores in memory.

Is there other key-value storage that have the same (set) functionality but stores on disk?

PS: set values are not predefined .

Comment: possible duplicate of [Alternatives to Redis Sets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12292297/alternatives-to-redis-sets)

Comment: not sO duplicate. super speed is not important.

Comment: @IlyaNovojilov: If you're not worried about speed, why not use an SQL database? A unique key is, after all, a set.

Comment: index update becomes a pain when you delete a quarter of many million records table.
But seems there is no other option but sql,you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution here - http://ssdb.io/

Not exactly as fast as Redis, but OK for my case.

Stores data on SSD disks.

Answer (score 0):

How big is the data set?

I've seen a redis instance with nearly a billion data points that only took up ~40GB.

Comment: 40G of RAM for only one table? Looks a bit expensive.

Answer (score 0):

BerkeleyDB and LMDB both support multiple values per key, and using their sorted duplicates feature would have the same properties as a set.